# Django sends emails twice after form submission

Tags: django, django-forms, django-email

I was trying to send emails when a form is submitted in my app, and I managed to do it but for some reason, it sends it twice every time.
After some search and debugging I think I know where the problem is but I don't know why.

So the email sending function of my app takes place in my forms. py and looks like this:

```
class approvalForm(forms.ModelForm):
    text1 = forms.ModelChoiceField(disabled = True, queryset = Visit.objects.all())
    text2 = forms.ChoiceField(disabled = True, choices = poolnumber)

def save(self, commit=False):
      instance = super(approvalForm, self).save(commit=commit)
      ready = instance.visible
      if ready is True:
        self.send_email()
        print('yay sent')
      else:
          None
      return instance

def send_email(self):
    var = self.cleaned_data
    tomail = self.cleaned_data.get('visit')
    tomails = tomail.location.users.all()
    tomaillist = []
    for item in tomails:
        tomaillist.append(item.email)
    print(tomaillist)
    msg_html = render_to_string('myapp/3email.html', {'notify': var})
    msg = EmailMessage(
          'Text here',
          msg_html,
          'myemail@email.com',
          tomaillist,
          headers={'Message-ID': 'foo'},
       )
    msg.content_subtype = "html"
    print("Email sent")
    msg.send() 


class Meta:
    model = MyModels
    fields = ('text1','text2', )
```

The save() function is running 2 times. I've tried to move the email sending function to the views.py in the form_valid() function but it's never called so I've tried the form_invalid() but the same results.

Is there any way to not let the save() function run 2 times? Or is this because of some error in my code?

Comment: you are saving `instance` 2 time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and change your `save()` method to this:

```
def save(self, commit=True):  # declaration matches the method you are overriding
    instance = super(approvalForm, self).save(commit=False)
    ready = instance.visible
    if ready:   # no need to include is True
       self.send_email()
    if commit:
        instance.save()
```

Comment: This solved the problem thanks! Now in the consol I see only one print! But it also gives me an error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__dict__'. I'm not sure what this means

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/why-do-i-get-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something

Comment: @VendelUtto Please consider marking this as accepted if it solved you problem.The other issue you are having seems like it is related to something else.

Answer (score 1):

When overriding the save() method, you should do the call to super() at the end.

Furthermore, overriding this method should be used only to add some checks of other things before effectively saving your instance. Here I see you do a save() on instance..in the save() method.

The effective save() on your instance, which is 'self' here, should be done only once through the super()

And there is no need to return anything when overriding save(). Just finish with the super() and everything will be ok.

Comment: Also:
Why do you retrieve instance through the super().save() without the commiting (by default) ?
Why do you have a "else: None" ??
"if ready is True:" could be written as follow : "if ready:"